# start cuda (use of libraries or API s)

Tags: cuda

I want to start CUDA in C++ and I familiar with C++ , Qt and C#.

But i want to know it's better to use from CUDA libraries -at high level- or CUDA API s -at the lower level- ?

Is it more better that I'm starting from API and dont use of CUDA driver ?
(I start on "*cuda by example*" for its concepts in parallel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are familiar with C/C++, you'd better use the higher-level API, CUDA C or C for CUDA, which is more convenient to easy to write, because it consists of a minimal set of extensions to the C language and a runtime library.

The lower-level API, which is the CUDA driver API that provides an additional level of control by exposing lower-level concepts, requires more code, is harder to program and debug, but offers a better level of control and is language-independent since it handles binary or assembly code.

See Chapter 3 of [CUDA programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) for more details.